# allow users to publish without admin approval

Tags: php, plugin-development

i have a website for ads, when a user want to add an ad he have to login then added his ad from frontend, but this ad will need an admin approval, i want to add an option to my theme that allow my users to publish thier ads without admin approval. any idea on how to do this

Comment: It's possible to make database query to make those ads published,, however, you need to provide more information. What to you use to create ad. / user subscription etc? Please provide more information (minimal executable CODE if possible) if you want a solid answer.

Comment: You might try [Inline Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) - edit whichever role your ad creators are using and grant them publishing capability. Depending on how it's set up you might have publish_ads, publish_posts, or some other custom permission to enable this.

Comment: this have something to do with `wp_insert_post()` but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: never mind, i have find the solution